# Component Library and automatic calculations with FPeval

Tags: fp

I have come upon a problem I'd like to solve but unable to by myself. My intention is to create a library of components with different parameters and do calculations with FPeval. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\usepackage{xstring}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\usepackage{color}

%STRUCT
\newcommand \Rmin[2]{\ensuremath{\FPeval{\result}{round(#1-(#1*#2/100),2)}\result}}
\newcommand \Rmax[2]{\ensuremath{\FPeval{\result}{round(#1+(#1*#2/100),2)}\result}}

\newcommand\defResCMtype[2]{%defined VARIOUS types
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname TOL#1\endcsname{#2}
}
\newcommand\defResCM[3]{%
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname value#1\endcsname{#2}
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1min\endcsname{
        \StrDel{#3}{ }[\tmp]% remove spaces and store the string in \tmp
        \IfEqCase{\tmp}{{typeX}{\Rmin{#2}{\TOLtypeX}}
        }%
        [{\color{red}XXXXXX}] %ERROR
    }
    \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1max\endcsname{
        \StrDel{#3}{ }[\tmp]% remove spaces and store the string in \tmp
        \IfEqCase{\tmp}{{typeX}{\Rmax{#2}{\TOLtypeX}}
        }%
        [{\color{red}XXXXXX}] %ERROR
    }
}

%LIB
\defResCMtype{typeX}{5}

\defResCM{compX}{100}{typeX}

%CALC
\newcommand \calc[2]{\ensuremath{\FPeval{\result}{round(#1,#2)}\result}}

\newcommand \testcalcA{\ensuremath{\calc{(105 / 95)}{2}}} %calculated with numbers
\newcommand \testcalcB{\ensuremath{\calc{((\compXmax)/(\compXmin))}{2}}} %calculated with macros -> NOT WORKING


\begin{document}

test = \valuecompX \\
test2= \compXmax \\
test3= \compXmin \\

A = \testcalcA \\ %-> WORKING
%B = \testcalcB \\ %-> NOT WORKING

\end{document}
```

If I manually enter the numbers created from the `test2` & `test3` then FPeval calculates the equation `A`, however, if I want to pass these values automatically as `(\compXmax)` & `(\compXmin)` or even `comXmax` & `comXmin` in

```
\newcommand \testcalcB{\ensuremath{\calc{((\compXmax)/(\compXmin))}{2}}}
```

I get an error `! Use of \@newline doesn't match its definition.\kernel@ifnextchar ...rved@d =#1\def \reserved@a {#2}\def \reserved@b {#3}\f... B = \testcalcB`.

Manually inserting numbers between calculations in a document is error prone which I would very much like to avoid, since updating a parameter directly in library would need an update to the whole document where these parameters are used.

Comment: As it stands you are not actually assigning numbers to `\compXmax` and `\compXmin`, and your string operations are not expandable. Can you explain what the above implements so we can avoid having to work that out and can make useful code suggestions?

Comment: Thank you for a kind welcome Mr. @Hupfer. The idea of above code is to build a library with components such as `\defResCM{compX}{100}{typeX}`, set its value and divide it by type. From these parameters calculate the minimum, maximum value and use these in other equations. Therefore avoid re-typing minmax values which is rather error prone when there are hundreads or more components used. That is why I would like to have a separate file with stored components. Tried the code below from @Steven B. Segletes and it works, but I'm not fond of a library in the document.

Comment: @MAAG If you prefer the library in the preamble, I will revise.  I did it because an error in the library printed out text, which cannot happen in the preamble.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That would be very appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: @MAAG In the preamble, using my answer, you can say `\AtBeginDocument{\defResCMtype{typeX}{5}\defResCM{compX}{100}{typeX}}`, which works fine with the present construct.

Comment: Please see revision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is you want `\compXmin` and `\compXmax` to be evaluated already at their assignment, without the actual calculation embedded in their definitions.

EDITED to allow library to be set in the preamble (which was mentioned in a comment of the OP), through the use of `\AtBeginDocument{}`.
RE-EDITED to save intermediate calculations (`\testcalcB` result saved in `\thetestcalcB`, `\testcalcC` result saved in `\thetestcalcC`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fp}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fp
\usepackage{xstring}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring
\usepackage{xparse}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse
\usepackage{xcolor}

%STRUCT
\newcommand \Rmin[2]{\ensuremath{\FPeval{\result}{round(#1-(#1*#2/100),2)}%
  \xdef\theRmin{\result}}}
\newcommand \Rmax[2]{\ensuremath{\FPeval{\result}{round(#1+(#1*#2/100),2)}%
  \xdef\theRmax{\result}}}

\newcommand\defResCMtype[2]{%defined VARIOUS types
    \expandafter\def\csname TOL#1\endcsname{#2}%
\ignorespaces}
\newcommand\defResCM[3]{%
    \expandafter\def\csname value#1\endcsname{#2}%
        \StrDel{#3}{ }[\tmp]% remove spaces and store the string in \tmp
        \IfEqCase{\tmp}{{typeX}{\Rmin{#2}{\TOLtypeX}\Rmax{#2}{\TOLtypeX}%
                                \expandafter\xdef\csname #1max\endcsname{\theRmax}%
                                \expandafter\xdef\csname #1min\endcsname{\theRmin}%
                               }%
                       }%
        [{\unskip\textcolor{red}{ERROR DEFINING: #1}\par}] %ERROR
\ignorespaces}
%LIB
\AtBeginDocument{
\defResCMtype{typeX}{5}
\defResCM{compX}{100}{typeX}
\defResCMtype{typeX}{10}
\defResCM{altX}{150}{typeX}
\defResCM{compY}{200}{type Y}
}
%CALC
\newcommand \calc[2]{\ensuremath{\FPeval{\result}{round(#1,#2)}}%
                     \xdef\thecalc{\result}}

\newcommand \testcalcB[1]{\ensuremath{\calc{((\csname#1max\endcsname)/%
                          (\csname#1min\endcsname))}{2}}%
                          \edef\thetestcalcB{\thecalc}\thetestcalcB}

\newcommand \testcalcC[1] {\ensuremath{\calc{(\thetestcalcB * \csname#1min\endcsname)}%
                          {2}}\edef\thetestcalcC{\thecalc}\thetestcalcC}
\begin{document}
test = \valuecompX \par
test2= \compXmax \par
test3= \compXmin \par
\medskip
B = \testcalcB{compX} \par %-> NOW WORKING
C = \testcalcC{compX} \par %-> NOW WORKING
\medskip
test = \valuealtX \par
test2= \altXmax \par
test3= \altXmin \par
\medskip
B = \testcalcB{altX} \par %-> NOW WORKING
C = \testcalcC{altX} \par %-> NOW WORKING
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great, it works, thank you. Is there also a possibility that this combination would work with reusing this`\newcommand \testcalcB{{\calc{(compXmax * compXmin)}{2}}}` in this again `\newcommand \testcalcC{{\calc{(testcalcB * compXmin)}{2}}}`?

Comment: @MAAG Done.  I hope this serves your need.